# Can't get the current language in template file

Tags: magento2, template, language

I am trying to set language ico in the frontend.
I try to get the language name using `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default');`   but I get an error:
This is my setting.phtml

```
<?php
$id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '';
?>
<div class="custom-group setting-links dropdown" id="setting-links<?php echo $id?>">
    <a class="action toggle switcher-trigger" id="setting-links" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"> </i><?php echo  Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default'); ?>
    </a>

    <div class="setting-links-options dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="setting-links">
        <div class="switcher-currency-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_custom') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="switcher-language-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language_custom') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This generates an error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in
>   /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/fasony/Magento_Theme/templates/html/setting.phtml:15

Comment: First of all please check your code...You are using magento 2 site and using magento 1 code...then how do you get the correct answer????

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.4. and the code I got it from other post so maybe it doesnt work for my case. any ideahow to fix that ?

Comment: hi. added a new code to get language. please check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current using laguage by below code:

> With objectManager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver'); 
echo $store->getLocale();
```

OR

> With Factory Method

```
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
    ...
    Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $store,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_store = $store;
    ...
}
```

Now use getLocale() to get laguage:

```
$currentStore = $this->_store->getLocale();

if($currentStore == 'en_US'){

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found it already in this blog https://mage2.pro/t/topic/58 , but I will accept your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set yourself either an override block, or a helper that allows you access to `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

Just Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`, in your constructor argument and set a class property: `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;`

To get a specific configuration attribute, just use:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/country/default', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Assuming you wanted to implement this as a `helper`, then you'd be looking at something like the following:

`app/code/<vendor>/<namespace>/Helper/Config.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Config extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    function __construct()
    {
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function getDefaultCountry()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/country/default', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

}
```

In your template, you'd call:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('\Vendor\Namespace\Helper\Config');
echo $_helper->getDefaultCountry();
```

Comment: I get : 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::$scopeConfig in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110

Comment: where do I find the constructor ?

Comment: Have you implemented this directly into the template?